# What is the meaning of "I'm" at the end of a song?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've heard a christian song on YouTube which is "Mary did you know". At the end of this song they said: "The sleeping child you're holding is the great I am".

I do not understand the meaning of "I'm" in this case.

[Here is the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifCWN5pJGIE), The sentence is at 2:49 .

Thank you very much,

Comment: 'I am', never 'I'm' in this usage. You could look at [Gotquestions.org: What did Jesus mean when He said 'I AM'?](http://www.gotquestions.org/I-AM.html). Follow especially the Exodus 3:14 reference.

Comment: You've got your answer. Please don't instruct people who've got to know the requirements of ELU over many years about how to administer the site. 'When in Rome, ...'

Comment: Ok I'm sorry :) I did not mean anything negative

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a biblical allusion: the sleeping Child is Jesus, who is theologically not only the Son of God but also the second 'Person' of God Himself. At Exodus 3:14 God informs Moses in a complex Hebrew pun that His Name is **I AM**.

> 13 And Moses said unto God, Behold, when I come unto the children of Israel, and shall say unto them, The God of your fathers hath sent me unto you; and they shall say to me, What is his name? what shall I say unto them?
>
> 14 And God said unto Moses, **I Am That I Am**: and he said, Thus shalt thou say unto the children of Israel, **I Am** hath sent me unto you.
>      —*Authorized Version*

The song thus identifies the Child as God, “***I AM***”

Comment: I second StoneyB's answer.
So, the line in question says this: The sleeping child you're holding is the great "I AM." The words "I AM" is taken as a proper noun for God and "the great" describes it.